# Does "should not confine [something to something] alone" mean "should look around more"?

Tags: meaning, expressions

[A Cambridge english Vocabulary](https://www.cambridgeenglish.org/Images/84669-pet-vocabulary-list.pdf) says

> The list does not provide an exhaustive list of all words which appear on the Preliminary and Preliminary for Schools question papers and candidates `should not` `confine` their study of vocabulary to the list `alone`.

Does "should not confine their study of vocabulary to the list alone" mean candidates "should look around/look for more vocabulary lists"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's one way the phrase could be interpreted, especially if one reads the phrase very literally. but there is a subtler meaning to be understood in this context.

The context is the study of vocabulary, not the study of lists. When we study vocabulary we study words. The list is a list of words that appear on the question papers, but the statement says that the list doesn't include all of the words which appear on the question papers.  So the subtler meaning is that candidates should study other words besides those on the list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is the difference between vocabulary and words, in "When we study vocabulary we study words"?

Comment: Vocabulary is the collection of words that makes up the language. Is that clear for you?